# Inventor Design Automation with Modelstates not working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-inventor

I had a bug today with an assembly that is using model states. It is handled by the design automation. So I just did a simple example.

There is a Quader, a cylinder and a sphere.
[sample bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuAhu.png)

With the help of modelstates and iLogic only one of them is shown. There is a parameter that has three options:

[parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zEbC.png)

Depending on what is selected the model state switches. This works by using some iLogic:

```
If Config = "Quader" Then
    ThisDoc.ActiveModelState = "Quader"
Else If Config = "Cylinder" Then
    ThisDoc.ActiveModelState = "Cylinder"
Else If Config = "Kugel" Then
    ThisDoc.ActiveModelState = "Kugel"
End If
```

This works locally but not when using it with forge design automation. Im happy to show you a sample but if you want to have a look at this video :
https://youtu.be/a9YQxsZuobo

in a more complex sample there seams to be much more things not working like parameter values not updating or position of model is wrong.

Comment: We are not sure why this might be happening. It would be great if you can provide the sample files for us to review. Please send to the forge.help@autodesk.com alias and reference Chandra who will be investigating and assisting you. If it's too large for email, you can provide a link to a cloud storage location of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

After watching your video, it is understood that you are looking for assembly configurator using model states.

Now, forge sample code and testing assembly are prepared to find out the workaround. Finally, the workaround is to add one more extra parameter 'None' to assembly and save assembly with 'None' parameter as default parameter. Whenever the other 3 parameters are changed, it triggers event triggers. Which in turn executes iLogic rule to change the model state of assembly.

To demonstrate the same screencast is prepared and uploaded to below link.

https://autode.sk/3J6BjMq

Forge sample code and testing assembly used in above video are uploaded to this  [link](https://myshare.autodesk.com/:f:/r/personal/chandra_shekar_gopal_autodesk_com/Documents/11259?csf=1&web=1&e=ExxLpg). Access to this link has been given to tobias.wiesendanger@mum.ch

Thanks and regards,
Chandra shekar G

Comment: I tried that with a more complex model and it doesnt behave like it does locally. There are things that are supressed and dont get unsupressed when changing modelstates. I then deleted the modelstates and it looks like frame generator also doesnt work in forge. Maybe you can confirm or deny that frame generator doesnt work with design automation. This was also the case for Config 360.

Comment: Frame Generator is not supported on DA4I: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/restrictions/#design-automation-api-for-inventor
Could you provide a non-confidential model that could be used to reproduce the issue?